# How to get where I was before entering into widget in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10

Here I met a problem, in iOS10 , we have three ways to open widget,

1.Pull down notification center and swipe left.

2.At main screen and swipe left.

3.Force touch your app and get the widget with the compact mode.

The problem is that , is there any way to know which method I used to step

into the widget viewcontroller?

Comment: Why does it matter which way we got there?

Comment: We want to record the statistics data of these  users' operation